# jwplayer cant detect if my video changes

Tags: javascript, html, video, streaming, jwplayer

Im using jwplayer, this is how I install it:

```
jwplayer("flowplayer1").setup({
    file: '/path/to/video.flv',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    autostart: true,
    stretching: 'exactfit',
    ratio: "100%",
    responsive: true
});
```

the problem is, when this video.flv changes, the player plays the old video. It cant detect if the video changed on the disk, even if I refreshed the browser (newest Firefox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not linked to JWPlayer, but with your browser cache.
You can try to

1. Refresh the page with CTRL+F5
2. Clear the cache
3. Test into another browser
4. Launch [another Firefox instance with another user profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Opening_a_new_instance_of_Firefox_with_another_profile)
5. add ?version=X at the end of your file to force browser cache invalidation

   `file: '/path/to/video.flv?version=X',`

Comment: yes, the "?version="+new Date().getTime()" did help.

Comment: Try to add a random # to your file using JavaScript.